# New Shipping method but Shopping Cart Price Rules is not appllied

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules

Following this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747 i have created a new shipping method

[image]

and the price, following the tutorial, has been set up in the file config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Envato_Customshippingmethod>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Envato_Customshippingmethod>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <envato_customshippingmethod>
        <class>Envato_Customshippingmethod_Model</class>
      </envato_customshippingmethod>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <envato_customshippingmethod>
        <class>Envato_Customshippingmethod_Helper</class>
      </envato_customshippingmethod>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <default>
    <carriers>
      <envato_customshippingmethod>
        <active>1</active>
        <sallowspecific>1</sallowspecific>
        <model>envato_customshippingmethod/demo</model>
        <name>Demo Shipping Method One</name>
        <price>8.53</price>
        <title>Demo Shipping Method</title>
      </envato_customshippingmethod>
    </carriers>
  </default>
</config>
```

The new shipping method appear to work fine, without any kind of problem, but if i try to set up a checkout rule to put the shipping method free for order over 30,00€ the rules is not applied

[image]

[image]

Maybe is a problem of the new shipping method?....or maybe i wrong something in the rule?

Answer (score 1):

I made it to work in this way finally, Go to your Model file mine is `Carrier.php`
and inside **public function** `collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)` you have to add the code below:

```
    if ($request->getFreeShipping()) {
        /**
         *  If the request has the free shipping flag,
         *  append a free shipping rate to the result.
         */
        $freeShippingRate = $this->_getFreeShippingRate();
        $result->append($freeShippingRate);
    }
```

After that, you have to add allow the free method inside the **public function** `getAllowedMethods()` as below:

```
    return array(
        'standard'    =>  'Standard Method',
        'free_shipping' => 'Free Shipping', //Add this one into your array
    );
```

After that you have to add a new function for the free shipping of course as below:

```
protected function _getFreeShippingRate()
{
    /** @var Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method $rate */
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $rate->setCarrierTitle('Envato'); //Change with your carrier name
    $rate->setMethod('free_shipping');
    $rate->setMethodTitle('Free Shipping');
    $rate->setPrice(0);
    $rate->setCost(0);

    return $rate;
}
```

When you finish this edits you will find that cart price rules with free shipping option will be applied normally on your custom shipping method.

Please accept it as Answer, I was trying to get it work for 2 months like you, and just fixed it yesterday.